# Creating a table from another

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a table(my) from Person_Permissions table. I am using a stored procedure which has two parameters(@username Varchar(20), @tableName Varchar(20)).

I have the following code which is throwing an error:

> The multi-part identifier "modise@gmail.com" could not be bound.

My Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myPermissions](@username VARCHAR(20), @tableName VARCHAR(20))
AS
DECLARE @sSQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sSQL = 'SELECT * INTO my FROM [' + @tableName + '_Permissions] WHERE userName =' + @username
EXECUTE(@sSQL)
```

Comment: You have more than 1 issue wrong here. The way this is written means that fixing the current error still leaves you a major problem. You can't execute this procedure more than once because the table "my" will exist. This procedure is also vulnerable to sql injection. You should wrap the table name variable in QUOTENAME and then use parameterized dynamic sql for the rest of it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better approach than simply making the dynamic sql work. This parameterizes your dynamic query and protects against sql injection. You still have the problem that you are creating a table named "my" every time this runs.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myPermissions]
(
    @username VARCHAR(20)
    , @tableName VARCHAR(20)
) AS

DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sSQL = 'SELECT * INTO my FROM [' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + '_Permissions] WHERE userName = @username'
exec sp_executesql @sSQL, N'@username varchar(20)', @username = @username
```

Answer (score 2):

A safer approach is to use `sp_executesql`. Something like the following:

```
declare @actualTableName VARCHAR(100) = @tableName + '_Permissions'
declare @sSQL NVARCHAR(4000) = N'
   SELECT * INTO my 
   FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@actualTableName) + '
   WHERE userName = @username'

EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, '@username VARCHAR(20)', @username = @username
```

This hybrid approach is required because table name cannot be provided as a parameter in dynamic queries, but `@username` can (and should) be.

Answer (score 1):

Missing single `'` at end

```
SET @sSQL = 'SELECT * INTO my FROM [' + @tableName + '_Permissions] WHERE userName =''' + @username+'''
```